# Import goods from America to Germany

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, import-taxes

I am not an EU citizen. I'm planning to go to the United States in February and I was going to buy computer parts there and bring them here, because the prices of parts are so expensive here. I read a lot of information on how much I’m allowed to bring and I'm pretty sure it's 430 Euros.

If I buy the parts in America on a website and it's around 420 Euros but it goes over 430 Euros with tax, does that count or does it have to be 430 Euros or less with tax included?

Also I'm going with my family and I was wondering if I can get 430 Euros worth of parts and my dad can get 430 Euros worth of parts separately with different names on the receipts. Will that work or is it 430 Euros all together as a family?

Also I am 15, so am I only allowed to bring 175 Euros worth of goods?

Answer (score 1):

Its the value in the EU that counts. If it costs €440 including tax in the EU, then you cannot import it for free, no matter how much you paid.

On the other hand, it is per person, so your mum, your dad, your brother and your sister can each import under the limit. As long as it is for personal use. So they might have to state that their parts or for them, not for you.

Comment: I think it is not *quite* accurate. If you have no invoices or if the invoices look fraudulent, that's what they *may* do. With invoices for realistic amounts of money, those invoices would be the basis of tariffs and import VAT.